# Symfoyn 3.4 : FOS User Bundle : Override Controller

Tags: symfony, overriding, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I'm working with Symfoyn 3.4 lts and I tried to override FOS User Bundle loginAction.

PS: from Symfony 3.4, bundle inheritance become deprecated, 
so to override an action just create an action with the same Route.

So, at first I created a bundle that I called src/MyVendor/MyVendorFOSUserBundle

second, I copied SecurityController.php from vendor/ in my bundle Controller/ And I put the Route Decorator above the loginAction but I get an issue when submiting login form => Invalid CSRF token: 
by debuggin I fount that the **$tokenManager** doesn't be injected in the Controller so it's take null value:
In this code I just added the @Route decorator and extends BaseController to the Contoller copied.

```
#src/MyVendor/MyVendorFOSUserBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php:

    class SecurityController extends BaseController
    {
    private $tokenManager;

    public function __construct(CsrfTokenManagerInterface $tokenManager = null)
    {
        $this->tokenManager = $tokenManager;
    }
     /**
      * @param Request $request
      * @return Response
      * @Route("/login")
      */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    { ... }
```

So To try to correct this issue, I tried to add the attribute name in @Route Decorator and I kept the same route name as it is in FOS User Bundle but in this case the Controller of FOS User bundle which is executed and my new Controller was ignored ( I test this by putting die('test') on Controller contructor)

The Question What is the solution to correctly override this action ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i loaded the routes individually and pointing the login action to my cutom controller which extends the FOSUsercontroller with some custom logic.

```
fos_user_security_login:
   path: /login
   methods: [GET, POST]
   defaults: { _controller: 'YourUserBundle\Controller\SecurityController:loginAction' }

fos_user_security_check:
   path: /login_check
   methods: [POST]
   defaults: { _controller: fos_user.security.controller:checkAction }

fos_user_security_logout:
   path: /logout
   methods: [GET, POST]
   defaults: { _controller: fos_user.security.controller:logoutAction }
```

Then i registered the Controller as a server to solve the missing tokenService